# run a python script from another python script

Tags: python

i have a test script test.py inside which i am trying to run one more python script `bexec.app`(this is a python script). Actually `test.py` is just for my testing. The original script is a lengthy one and `bexec.app` is getting called inside in a command line.

I tried this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys
os.path.insert(0, 'current bexec script path')
import bexec.app
```

But this does not work -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test", line 5, in <module>
    import bexec.pphshaper
ImportError: No module named bexec.app
```

I donot want to change the bexec.app script to bexec_app.py because this follows some naming convention

bexec.app also has `#!/usr/bin/python` inside it.
how can i import my `bexec` script inside `test.py`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to run your bexec, not import it. And if so, regular

```
os.system('current bexec script path')
```

should be sufficient

Comment: actually they both are in the same path

Comment: Location is actually irrelevant. It was copied from your question

Answer (score 0):

Dot means subpackage structure to python, but it's still possible with `imp`.

below is `bexec.app` sample file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

a = 2
```

and this is how you can import it in your `test.py` file, look below for the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys, imp

my_module = imp.load_source('my_module', 'bexec.app')

print (my_module.a)
```